# Is there a faster sine function?

Tags: xna, c#, mathematics

I am working on generation 3d perlin noise. The C# Math library seems like overkill for what I need since most of its functions use double percision. I use Math.Sin() in several places to generate the noise. Does anyone know of a faster sine function?

Comment: There is [MathF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.mathf?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use a parabola to aproximate the value of the sine function. This has the advantage of having the roots at exactly -pi/2 and pi/2 which is usually not the case with other fast approximations based on the [TaylorSeries](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html) or [MaclaurinSeries](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html).

```
public float Sin(float x)
{
    const float B = 4 / PI;
    const float C = -4 / (PI*PI);

    return -(B * x + C * x * ((x < 0) ? -x : x));
}
```

Here is a comparison to the actual sine function:

[image]

Comment: This is indeed a great solution. Here is an excellent article from devmaster.net which describes why this works and gives some implementation details: http://www.devmaster.net/forums/showthread.php?t=5784

Comment: I don't know about C#, but the abs() function in most C environments will likely be faster than a branch (the ?: operator), when optimized.

Comment: I removed the Math.Abs() call because I assumed that this code might run on the Xbox 360 or Windows Phone 7. The JIT compiler  on Xbox 360 does not inline anything. A call to Math.Abs() is actually more expensive.

Comment: @reverbb Link is 404. [Here is a cached copy.](https://web.archive.org/web/20100613230051/http://www.devmaster.net/forums/showthread.php?t=5784)

Comment: @zfedoran Why do you negate the return value? It appears to be a negative sine wave.

Answer (score 12):

What is the range of input values to your *sin()* function? For what you're using it for, it sounds like they might be limited, which means you could **pre-compute the values**. For instance, if you're rounding up the input values to the nearest degree, then you only have 360 possible values - just pre-compute them and store in a table.

If you need slightly more values, say to one decimal place, you could interpolate from the table - I'm not familiar with *perlin noise*, but the word "noise" seems to indicate it doesn't require high accuracy. :) (You could also just make a larger table, 3600 entries isn't much space).

Comment: If speed is your number-one concern, and you do not mind sacrificing a bit of accuracy, this is the best answer.

Comment: I don't know about "best" - As shown in another answer, you can get another very good approximation in five ops + abs (the speed of which depends on your arch / compiler, but is often branchless). If the lookup table is not in cache, it's going to be much slower.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to read [this](http://lab.polygonal.de/2007/07/18/fast-and-accurate-sinecosine-approximation/) too, it's got fast sine and cosine approximations

Comment: This link is 404. But you can find a backup here: http://web.archive.org/web/20110925033606/http://lab.polygonal.de/2007/07/18/fast-and-accurate-sinecosine-approximation/